In a MAUI android app, how do I have a shell that has both a flyout and a TabBar at the bottom
I've tried various combinations of the code below to show an App Shell that has both a flyout in the hamburger menu, containing links to one set of pages, and a TabBar at the bottom containing another set of links to other pages. But none seem to work.
In the example below I get a hamburger flyout, but that contains no menu items, and a tab bar at the top, which contains no images.
If I create just Flyout or just a TabBar, then I get the expected Flyout or TabBar, but never both.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MyTestMauiApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTestMauiApp"
    Title="MyTestMauiApp">

    <!-- Flyout Menu -->
    <FlyoutItem Title="Test MAUI App">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Settings" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" />
            <ShellContent Title="Main" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page3}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    
    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Home" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Settings" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SettingsPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Main" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>


Note: Shell  in general expects use to use either Flyout or a TabBar. Not both in parallel.
Now, There are few thing wrong with your code.

In the example below I get a hamburger flyout, but that contains no menu items, and a tab bar at the top, which contains no images.

You only defined only one flyout item Test MAUI App. Only that will be displayed(automatically get's selected since it's first defined).
Next, Inside the FlyoutItem you only defined one tab. And three content pages. You should define the tabs same as you defined in TabBar
 <FlyoutItem Title="Test MAUI App">
    <Tab Title="Home" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
        <ShellContent Title="Home" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page1}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Settings" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
        <ShellContent Title="Settings" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page2}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Main" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
        <ShellContent Title="Main" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:Page3}" />
    </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>

Above code will give you Flyout with one FlyoutItem and Tabbar with three options with images and text
You can add more flyout item's and Tab's to those separately to achieve what you were trying to achieve. But, Every time you navigate through different FlyoutItem a new instance of tab pages will be created. Which is not something you want in real-time scenario.

Great thanks, that all makes sense
